# Node.JS proxy using request module

Tags: node.js, express, proxy, request

I have an Express.JS application that makes a proxy call for a route using request Node module. This was working well with NodeJS V0.10.28; however, upgrading to NodeJS V4.4.7 has caused this to fail -- throwing an error "Error: write after end".

I am new to NodeJS; so I appreciate your help.

```
var bodyParser=require('body-Parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '100mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

....
....

app.use('/relay', function (req, res) {
        var request = require('request'),
            proxyUrl = 'http://abc.proxy.xyz:12345',
            apiEndPoint = "https://aaa.bbb.ccc/svc";

        req.pipe(request.post(apiEndPoint,{ proxy: proxyUrl, form: req.body}, function (error, response, body) {

            if (error) {
                console.log(error)
            } else {
                console.log("No error here.")
            }

            res.end();

        })).pipe(res);   
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity, here is my solution, in case someone else should face the same problem.

The problem was with the use of the middleware body-parser: body-parser reads the request to completion - and therefore the stream has reached its end. Therefore, req.pipe() -- in /relay route shown in the question -- does not have anything to read, and it won't restart the stream.

The returned error message "write after end" is quite ambiguous, though. It is also a mystery why I did not face this issue with Node.JS V0.10.28. The reported problem was noticed in V4.4.7

So, to work around the body-parser problem, I moved the /relay route to above the calls to body-parser:

```
app.use('/relay', function (req, res) {
        var request = require('request'),
            proxyUrl = 'http://abc.proxy.xyz:12345',
            apiEndPoint = "https://aaa.bbb.ccc/svc";

        req.pipe(request.post(apiEndPoint,{ proxy: proxyUrl, form: req.body}, function (error, response, body) {

            if (error) {
                console.log(error)
            } else {
                console.log("No error here.")
            }

            res.end();

        })).pipe(res);   
});

....
....

var bodyParser=require('body-Parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '100mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
```